# Can I pass COPY of a variable that it's a pointer?

Tags: c, queue, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm kind of new on C programming and I have the following issue.

I have a `char *` that will store a string with any amount of characters and I'm adding this string to a queue. Then I want to add more strings to that queue so I made the following code:
(I'm reading the strings from a binary file)

```
char *follower;

while (n!=0) {
    
    follower = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));    

    /*
       ... Code where I fill follower string using reallocs etc ...
    */

    QUEUE_add(follower);

    free(follower);
}
```

As I tried compiling this, I noticed that the queue always is empty because of the `free` I wrote after `QUEUE_add`. I wrote it to re-use `follower` variable in order to fill up the queue.

How would be the way to "send" a copy of what `follower` stores so it adds properly to the queue?

Comment: OT but you should also be aware that malloc(sizeof(char)) is allocating only a single byte, which is not useful for storing a string as it only has room for the string terminator (i.e. you could only store an empty string).  Also, sizeof(char) is always 1 by definition, so you should instead do malloc(n+1) where n is max length of string you want to store and the +1 gives space for the string terminator.

Comment: I initialize the `follower` string with a malloc (maybe this is redundant) and then I ask for more memory using reallocs till all the string is complete. Didn't write that in the example, my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are storing the pointer and freeing it after that you will loose access to that memory and what is stored there.

Keep in mind that if you simply assing the pointer to a new pointer you are simply making the new pointer point to the same memory location, if you free one you free the other leaving it dangling.

*e.g.*:

```
char *ptr = calloc(20, sizeof *ptr); //memory for string
char *ptr2 = ptr; //assing ptr to ptr2
free(ptr2); //the memory allocated for ptr2 and ptr is freed, ptr is now a dangling pointer
```

To reuse the pointer you'll need to copy the data pointed by `follower` with something like `strcpy` or `memcpy` before that.

---

Usage example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char dest[2][30]; // final container for the string
    
    char *ptr = calloc(20, sizeof *ptr); //memory for string

    char *my_str = "This is my string"; //test string
    
    memcpy(ptr, my_str, 20); //copying string to the memory pointed by ptr for test purposes

    memcpy(dest[0], ptr, sizeof *dest); //copying string to the destination container

    char *other_string = "This is my other string"; //other string to store

    ptr = realloc(ptr, 25); //reallocating ptr capacity to store the other string

    memcpy(ptr, other_string, 25);  //storing the  other string in ptr for example purposes

    memcpy(dest[1], ptr, sizeof *dest); //copying other string to its destination

    free(ptr); //freeing ptr when it's no longer needed

    printf("%s\n%s", dest[0], dest[1]); //test print
}
```

This is a simpified example, needless to say that you should always test the return values of `calloc` and `realloc` to assure the success of the memory allocation.

---

Side note:

In

```
follower = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));
```

Don't cast `malloc`, it hides a potencial fail to `#include <stdlib.h>` which is where `malloc` is declared.